# What difference does it makes to change the order of these words?

Tags: word-order

changing order of words in this text:

1 - "covid and diabetes collide in a public health train wreck"

rewriting it as:

2 - "covid and diabetes collide in a  train wreck public health"

OR

3 - "covid and diabetes collide in a public train wreck health"

do they all hold same gist???

Comment: FYI "do they all hold [the] same gist?" is not a grammatical question. You probably meant "do they all have the same meaning?"

Answer (score 2):

The first one is grammatical.

The second one and third are completely ungrammatical.

"Public health" is functioning is an adjective. "Train wreck" is a noun phrase. So a "public health train wreck" is comparable with a phrase like "policy disaster".

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about either 2 or 3. In fact, the grammar of 3 matches the grammar of 1 exactly. Your concern is probably semantic.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney Don't follow your logic. Steve seems to me to have got it right., I would assume that anyone using constructions 2 or 3 had very little knowledge of English.

Comment: @all, isn't there a semantic difference among these three?? I've started this question with this thought in mind unfortunately I did not make that clear

Comment: @JeffreyCarney #2 and #3 are grammatically questionable because we virtually never refer to "a health", and *health* is the main noun in #2 and #3.

Comment: @Lynerapintcho I don't think you can examine semantic differences between two sentences if one of them is ungrammatical. It doesn't really have a meaning to be examined.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about semantic differences, the answer is that re-ordering the words changes what is the main noun and what is the attributive noun, and for #2 and #3, that change makes the sentence nonsensical.

In a [*noun adjunct*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/noun-adjunct) construction, the main noun comes last, and it is modified by an adjectival noun that comes before it.  You can't reorder the words, because English does not [mark](https://teflpedia.com/Grammatical_marker) nouns for functioning as an adjective, so we depend on the order of words for meaning, and changing the order changes the meaning.  For example:

- a *race horse* is a horse.  What kind of horse?  One for races.
- a *horse race* is a race.  What kind of race?  One of horses.

So #1 says that COVID and diabetes collide in a (metaphorical) train wreck.  What kind of train wreck?  A *public health* one.

#2 says that COVID and diabetes collide in a health.  That doesn't make sense semantically (what does it mean for them to collide in a health?) or grammatically (*health* is a mass noun, so we don't say "*a* health").  What kind of health?  One that is public and a train wreck.

#3 says that COVID and diabetes collide in a health.  Again, that doesn't make sense semantically or grammatically, and *health* is modified by "public train wreck" which doesn't make sense either - the health is the health of a public train wreck?